# Error during creating package index for rebar3

Tags: proxy, elixir, elixir-mix

Here is my problem. I can not build following elixir application on Windows7 behind proxy.
I am using git bash and I have set http_proxy and https_proxy env variables. Check is curl www.google.hr and I get response.

Repository is:
https://github.com/karlosmid/blitzy/network

Reproduction steps:
1. Clone the repo
2. cd to repo
3. mix escript.build
4. mix deps.get
5. mix escript.build
6.  DEBUG=1 mix escript.build

It is important to state that I am able to build on OsX that is not behind proxy.

Here is error log:

```
===> Load global config file c:/Users/etkkasm/.config/rebar3/rebar.config
===> Error loading package registry: {read_error,
                                      {file_error,
                                       "c:/Users/etkkasm/.cache/rebar3/hex/default/registry",
                                       eisdir}}
===> Package <<"rebar3_hex">> not found. Fetching registry updates and trying again...
===> Updating package registry...
===> Fetching registry from "https://repo.hex.pm:443/registry.ets.gz?"
===> Error creating package index: {badmatch,{error,eisdir}} [{rebar_prv_update,
                                                               do,1,
                                                               [{file,
                                                                 "/home/tristan/Devel/rebar3/_build/default/lib/rebar/src/rebar_prv_update.erl"},
                                                                {line,61}]},
                                                              {rebar_packages,
                                                               handle_missing_package,
                                                               3,
                                                               [{file,
                                                                 "/home/tristan/Devel/rebar3/_build/default/lib/rebar/src/rebar_packages.erl"},
                                                                {line,85}]},
                                                              {rebar_app_utils,
                                                               get_package,3,
                                                               [{file,
                                                                 "/home/tristan/Devel/rebar3/_build/default/lib/rebar/src/rebar_app_utils.erl"},
                                                                {line,301}]},
                                                              {rebar_app_utils,
                                                               update_source,
                                                               3,
                                                               [{file,
                                                                 "/home/tristan/Devel/rebar3/_build/default/lib/rebar/src/rebar_app_utils.erl"},
                                                                {line,247}]},
                                                              {rebar_app_utils,
                                                               dep_to_app,7,
                                                               [{file,
                                                                 "/home/tristan/Devel/rebar3/_build/default/lib/rebar/src/rebar_app_utils.erl"},
                                                                {line,228}]},
                                                              {rebar_app_utils,
                                                               '-parse_deps/6-lc$^0/1-0-',
                                                               6,
                                                               [{file,
                                                                 "/home/tristan/Devel/rebar3/_build/default/lib/rebar/src/rebar_app_utils.erl"},
                                                                {line,129}]},
                                                              {rebar_prv_install_deps,
                                                               handle_deps_as_profile,
                                                               4,
                                                               [{file,
                                                                 "/home/tristan/Devel/rebar3/_build/default/lib/rebar/src/rebar_prv_install_deps.erl"},
                                                                {line,141}]},
                                                              {rebar_plugins,
                                                               handle_plugin,
                                                               4,
                                                               [{file,
                                                                 "/home/tristan/Devel/rebar3/_build/default/lib/rebar/src/rebar_plugins.erl"},
                                                                {line,94}]}]
===> throw {error,{rebar_prv_update,package_index_write}} [{rebar_prv_update,
                                                            do,1,
                                                            [{file,
                                                              "/home/tristan/Devel/rebar3/_build/default/lib/rebar/src/rebar_prv_update.erl"},
                                                             {line,77}]},
                                                           {rebar_packages,
                                                            handle_missing_package,
                                                            3,
                                                            [{file,
                                                              "/home/tristan/Devel/rebar3/_build/default/lib/rebar/src/rebar_packages.erl"},
                                                             {line,85}]},
                                                           {rebar_app_utils,
                                                            get_package,3,
                                                            [{file,
                                                              "/home/tristan/Devel/rebar3/_build/default/lib/rebar/src/rebar_app_utils.erl"},
                                                             {line,301}]},
                                                           {rebar_app_utils,
                                                            update_source,3,
                                                            [{file,
                                                              "/home/tristan/Devel/rebar3/_build/default/lib/rebar/src/rebar_app_utils.erl"},
                                                             {line,247}]},
                                                           {rebar_app_utils,
                                                            dep_to_app,7,
                                                            [{file,
                                                              "/home/tristan/Devel/rebar3/_build/default/lib/rebar/src/rebar_app_utils.erl"},
                                                             {line,228}]},
                                                           {rebar_app_utils,
                                                            '-parse_deps/6-lc$^0/1-0-',
                                                            6,
                                                            [{file,
                                                              "/home/tristan/Devel/rebar3/_build/default/lib/rebar/src/rebar_app_utils.erl"},
                                                             {line,129}]},
                                                           {rebar_prv_install_deps,
                                                            handle_deps_as_profile,
                                                            4,
                                                            [{file,
                                                              "/home/tristan/Devel/rebar3/_build/default/lib/rebar/src/rebar_prv_install_deps.erl"},
                                                             {line,141}]},
                                                           {rebar_plugins,
                                                            handle_plugin,4,
                                                            [{file,
                                                              "/home/tristan/Devel/rebar3/_build/default/lib/rebar/src/rebar_plugins.erl"},
                                                             {line,94}]}]
===> Plugin rebar3_hex not available. It will not be used.
===> Expanded command sequence to be run: []
===> Expanded command sequence to be run: [{default,app_discovery},
                                           {bare,compile}]
===> Error loading package registry: {read_error,
                                      {file_error,
                                       "c:/Users/etkkasm/.cache/rebar3/hex/default/registry",
                                       eisdir}}
===> Package certifi-0.7.0 not found. Fetching registry updates and trying again...
===> Updating package registry...
===> Fetching registry from "https://repo.hex.pm:443/registry.ets.gz?"
===> Error creating package index: {badmatch,{error,eisdir}} [{rebar_prv_update,
                                                               do,1,
                                                               [{file,
                                                                 "/home/tristan/Devel/rebar3/_build/default/lib/rebar/src/rebar_prv_update.erl"},
                                                                {line,61}]},
                                                              {rebar_packages,
                                                               handle_missing_package,
                                                               3,
                                                               [{file,
                                                                 "/home/tristan/Devel/rebar3/_build/default/lib/rebar/src/rebar_packages.erl"},
                                                                {line,85}]},
                                                              {rebar_app_utils,
                                                               update_source,
                                                               3,
                                                               [{file,
                                                                 "/home/tristan/Devel/rebar3/_build/default/lib/rebar/src/rebar_app_utils.erl"},
                                                                {line,262}]},
                                                              {rebar_app_utils,
                                                               dep_to_app,7,
                                                               [{file,
                                                                 "/home/tristan/Devel/rebar3/_build/default/lib/rebar/src/rebar_app_utils.erl"},
                                                                {line,228}]},
                                                              {rebar_app_utils,
                                                               '-parse_deps/6-lc$^0/1-0-',
                                                               6,
                                                               [{file,
                                                                 "/home/tristan/Devel/rebar3/_build/default/lib/rebar/src/rebar_app_utils.erl"},
                                                                {line,129}]},
                                                              {rebar_app_discover,
                                                               '-do/2-fun-0-',
                                                               3,
                                                               [{file,
                                                                 "/home/tristan/Devel/rebar3/_build/default/lib/rebar/src/rebar_app_discover.erl"},
                                                                {line,37}]},
                                                              {lists,foldl,3,
                                                               [{file,
                                                                 "lists.erl"},
                                                                {line,1263}]},
                                                              {rebar_app_discover,
                                                               do,2,
                                                               [{file,
                                                                 "/home/tristan/Devel/rebar3/_build/default/lib/rebar/src/rebar_app_discover.erl"},
                                                                {line,33}]}]
===> {rebar_prv_update,package_index_write}
```

Comment: What version of `rebar3` are you on? Can you try updating it to the newest one?

Comment: @dogbert ~/.mix/rebar3 --version
===> Package <<"rebar3_hex">> not found. Fetching registry updates and trying again...  
===> Updating package registry...  
===> Plugin rebar3_hex not available. It will not be used.  
rebar 3.3.4 on Erlang/OTP 19 Erts 8.0

Comment: The error message seems to say something tried to read `c:/Users/etkkasm/.cache/rebar3/hex/default/registry` as a file but it was a directory (`eisdir`). On my OSX system, `~/.cache/rebar3/hex/default/registry` is indeed a file.

Comment: @dogbert `rm -r ~/.cache/rebar3/hex/default/registry`  `touch ~/.cache/rebar3/hex/default/registry` resolved the issue.